# Remembering state before app goes in foreground

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react native project and i have to implement a feature that when app is inactive it renders a logo screen and when app is active it renders the app.

I was able to accomplish this but my problem now is eg. if my main screen is the home screen and i am currently on my profile screen when i navigate between my app and another app then go back to my app i return to the home screen instead of the profile screen.

How do i fix this?

Should i save the current state on my app in AsyncStorage?

I am also using React Context API not redux.

Here is my code as requested:

```
const[isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
const[user,setUser]=useState();
const[authenticated,setAuthenticated]=useState();
const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] =useState(appState.current);

const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
if (
  appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
  nextAppState === "active"
) {
  console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
}

appState.current = nextAppState;
setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
console.log("AppState", appState.current);
};

 useEffect(() => {
 AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
  return () => {
  AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
  };
  }, []);

const restoreUser = async () => {
const user = await storage.getUser();
if (user) setUser(user);
};

if (!isReady)
return (
<AppLoading 
startAsync={restoreUser} 
onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} 
onError={console.warn}
/>
);  

return(
 (appState.current)==='active'?
 <AuthContext.Provider value= 
 {{user,setUser,authenticated,setAuthenticated}}>
 <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>
   {
   (user&&authenticated)?<AppNavigator/>
   :(user)?<PasscodeNavigator/>
   :<AuthNavigator/>
   }
 </NavigationContainer>
 </AuthContext.Provider>
 :
 <SplashScreen/>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not an answer. It was just a general suggestion, I do not think anyone can help without you showing some code. I don't think I can help personally because it was awhile since I used react-native, but maybe I can suggest things that I would look at. I would log the authenticated and user state and see if they are what you expect. If they are not what you expect then you might want to store them in localstorage or redux.

Comment: As @howtopythonpls suggested investigate authenticated state, there does not seem to be any setAuthenticated similar to restoreUser and your condition to show profile I guess is both (user && authenticated).

Comment: @agenthunt hi, thank you for getting back to me. my authenticated state is used to check is a user token exists then instead of rendering my welcome screen render my passcode screen. Currently my authenticated state is working properly, my problem is when i implement the above code eg. say i am on the settings screen and go to another app then back to dont return to the settings screen i return to my feed screen.

Comment: It is quite hard to figure out your app route structure without knowing the details. Again taking shots in the dark. Your route is probably not saved or the state that derives on what route your app needs to be in,  is not saved or not derived properly to make that restore back to proper screen?

Comment: @agenthunt in Tab Navigator component i specified my initial route name as my feed screen is that maybe why after i come from foreground i land there? What information do you require?

Comment: @kd12345 you can show/hide Splash modal instead of screen when app status change so in this way your navigator stack will remain on same position

Comment: @MehranKhan Thank you for getting back to me, will give that a try. Is it possible to only show this modal for specific screens?

Comment: @kd12345 A simple solution could be rendering a simple View at an absolute position containing the logo image that will cover the actual app. Render it based on the app state.

Comment: @SaachiTech is using a modal a good idea as the accepted answer suggests?

Comment: Both option are fine, I personally prefer to go with very simple solution, like I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can show/hide Splash in modal instead of screen when app status change**

```
import {  Modal } from "react-native";

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

const _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
  if (
    appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
    nextAppState === 'active'
  ) {
    setModalVisible(false);
  } else {
    setModalVisible(true);
  }
};


return (
  <>
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, setUser, authenticated, setAuthenticated }}
    >
      <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>
        {user && authenticated ? (
          <AppNavigator />
        ) : user ? (
          <PasscodeNavigator />
        ) : (
          <AuthNavigator />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
    <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
      <SplashScreen />
    </Modal>
  </>
);
```

Comment: I just tried the code you provided and it is still not working, not happens when i go to foreground. Should i add the useEffect in the code i provided?

Comment: I think i should put <Modal></Modal> inside my NavigationContainer

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem, you have another option, apart from saving state in AsyncStorage, you could wrap all app in one Navigation Container and redirect using navigation reference.

example:

```js
const { StyleSheet } = require('react-native');

const App = () =>{
  const[isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
const[user,setUser]=useState();
const[authenticated,setAuthenticated]=useState();
const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] =useState(appState.current);

const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
if (
  appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
  nextAppState === "active"
) {
  console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
}

appState.current = nextAppState;
setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
console.log("AppState", appState.current);
};

 useEffect(() => {
 AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
  return () => {
  AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
  };
  }, []);

const restoreUser = async () => {
const user = await storage.getUser();
if (user) setUser(user);
};

if (!isReady)
return (
<AppLoading 
startAsync={restoreUser} 
onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} 
onError={console.warn}
/>
);  

return(
 
 <AuthContext.Provider value= 
 {{user,setUser,authenticated,setAuthenticated}}>
 <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>
   {
   (user&&authenticated)?<AppNavigator/>
   :(user)?<PasscodeNavigator/>
   :<AuthNavigator/>
   }
 </NavigationContainer>
 { (appState.current)!=='active' && <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}><SplashScreen/></View> }
 </AuthContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, i just tried your solution and it is not working, the splash is the only screen getting rendered